# How to approach a file in visual webpart

Tags: 2010, development, web-part

To explain my question, lets consider I'm developing a webpart in Visual Studio, a visual webpart.

By default when I add a webpart to solution, it creates a MyWebPart wich exists of 3 files:
Elements.xml, MyWebpart.cs and MyWebpart.webpart.

Now lets imagine I'll add another file to this files, like hello.txt.

Now how can I access it then from this webpart, to read the text in the file?

Or how else can I have a file which would be a part of a webpart?

Answer (score 1):

As usual the answer is it depends.

The main thing you should consider is who you want to be able to change the content of the file and at what scope:

**Nobody should change it**
Add the file in a Mapped folder (see [Deploying files using Mapped Folders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/03/12/deploying-files-using-mapped-folders.aspx)) and access it using normal file I/O after getting the Path using [`SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getgenericsetuppath%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Note this isn't an option if you're creating a Sandboxed solution.

**Superusers should be able to change it using SharePoint Designer**
Add the file as `ghostable` in a Module (see [Using Modules to Include Files in the Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and access it using the [SPFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class.

**Users should be able to change it using the "Browser"**
Add the file to a document library as `ghostableinlibrary` in a Module (see [Using Modules to Include Files in the Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and access it using the [SPFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class.

**Users should be able to change it for each instance of the web part**
Add the content of the file as a property in your .webpart file and access it using a custom property in your webpart (see [Walkthrough: Creating a Basic Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817%28v=office.14%29.aspx))